# Extracting a single weakly connected component from a network of many weakly connected components?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Hello Mathematica friends!

I've got a network with thousands of edges and vertices, but not all in one connected component.  I'm trying to extract specific connected components from the network, and assign them as new variables.

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8}]
```

I know it's a disconnected component because of:

```
WeaklyConnectedGraphQ[g]
False
```

I know there are two components:

```
Length[WeaklyConnectedComponents[g]]
2
```

I know how many vertices are in each component:

```
Length /@ WeaklyConnectedComponents[g]
{5, 3}
```

And I know what vertices are in each component:

```
WeaklyConnectedComponents[g]
{{7, 6, 5, 8, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}
```

What I don't know is how to a assign on of these components to a new variable to then proceed with analysis on just a single connected component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that you want the subgraph of ***g*** that corresponds to the vertices in one of the w.c.c (say, the first one). How about:

```
Subgraph[g, First@WeaklyConnectedComponents[g]]
```

If you want, say, the 13th connected component, just do

```
Subgraph[g, WeaklyConnectedComponents[g][[13]] ]
```

Comment: That's perfect, and so simple! Thanks!

Comment: what if I wanted to second or third subgraph? I tried just replacing `First@WeaklyConnectedComponents` with `Second@WeaklyConnectedComponents` but that didn't appear to work.

Comment: @Curtis you should do WeaklyConnectedComponents[g][[2]]